# r shiny pdf display is blank

Tags: r, pdf, iframe, shiny

I'm trying to display an imported pdf in shiny app, below is reproducible code but the pdf viewer is blank after the import, not showing any errors either. Don't know how to make it work.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(pdftools)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Demo"),
  fileInput("file_import", "Upload Files", multiple = T, accept = ".pdf"),
  tableOutput("files"),
  uiOutput("pdfview")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$files <- renderTable({input$file_import})
  
  observeEvent(input$file_import,{
    
    output$pdfview <- renderUI({
      
        tags$iframe(style = 'height: 680px; width: 960px;scrolling=yes',
                    src = input$file_import$datapath)
      
    })
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works fine.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Testing File upload"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file_input', 'upload file ( . pdf format only)', accept = c('.pdf'))
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("pdfview")
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  observe({
    req(input$file_input)
    
    file.copy(input$file_input$datapath,"www", overwrite = T)
    
    output$pdfview <- renderUI({
      tags$iframe(style="height:600px; width:100%", src="0.pdf")
    })
    
  })
  
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Please ensure that you have a `www` folder and restart RStudio. It should work locally in a browser. Then try to deploy it and test it - after ensuring that there is a `www` folder under the folder where you keep your `app.R`.

Comment: I've seen this solution on SO as well, but it didn't work. When I import the pdf, the pdf view shows "Not Found".

Comment: Please note that the pdf file you are loading is copied to www folder, and then displayed.  Are you sure this code (as is) does not work for you to display pdf file?

Comment: I copy and paste your code and run it, upload a pdf stored on the local drive, and the display is "Not Found". Does it work on yours? I've tested it on both mac and windows, tested on safari and chrome, none of it works, all display "Not Found" Thanks

Comment: You should be able to find `0.pdf` in your www folder.  Please check it.  If you don't have a folder named www, you should create it under the current working folder where you keep your R programs.  This code works fine for me in RStudio.

Comment: I can see a www folder created after I run the code, but the folder is white colour and when I double click it to open, it asks me use what application to open it, not the type of folder I can double click and opened it.

Comment: When I use a pdf reader to open that www folder, it does open the pdf file. But I can't go into the folder and see there's a 0.pdf file. I'm also conscious that this is supposed to be easy for every users once deployed, and I shouldn't be expecting them to do anything else other than going to the website and upload the document.

Comment: Please ensure that you have a www folder and restart RStudio.  It should work locally.  Then try to deploy it and test it (after ensuring that there is a www folder under the folder where you keep your app.R).  This code works fine for me.  There is no need for users to access www folder directly as the pdf file will be displayed on the screen when the app is run.

Comment: ok it works now, those steps you mentioned are correct. And it works best on a browser so that the pdf can be opened inside the webpage. Can you update your answer to include those steps you just mentioned please? I think it can help people if they are stuck like me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234918/discussion-between-subaru-spirit-and-ybs).